# Footer navbar navigation in Titanium alloy

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am creating an alloy app in titanium appcelerator in which i have a requirement to have footer navigation menu with 5 options navigating to different pages,each sub page also have same footer navigation menu. I have question that what architecture should i use to keep every screen open in one view and there should be only one controller , because if i make each page a controller then it will be a big stack of controllers remain in memory when user will navigate through footer menu. Hope you understand if have any confusion you may ask again.

Kindly suggest what should be the best approach.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having multiple controllers in memory won't have a bigger memory footprint than one controller that is 5 times as big. Separation of concerns (splitting into multiple controllers) is almost always better.

What you're looking for is a [TabGroup](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup). In Alloy you can do that like this:

index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
  <TabGroup>
    <Tab>
      <Window></Window>
    </Tab>
  </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Best thing to do is replace the `<Window>` with a separate controller, like this (where the name is just a placeholder obviously)

```
<Tab>
  <Require src="firstTabWindow" />
</Tab>
```

Then in `firstTabWindow.xml`

```
<Alloy>
  <Window></Window>
</Alloy
```

If you need to know any specifics of stuff, just read the docs/guides or join the [slack](https://tislack.org) community and ask around there.